# React Hook Form don't register inputs when using Material UI stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using the default example from Material UI steppers, which can be found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#non-linear-alternative-label), along with React Hook Form, but when I register the fields, e.g on the first step, they are not submitted when the form is submitted at the last step, but the fields from the last step, where the submit button is, are submitted.

I tried to use the [provider](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance) but it didn't work, I tried to elevate where I use `useForm()` and use `useCallback(()=> {}, [])` so the reference is not lost between renders, but nothing worked... I have three levels (base component -> modal (tried `useForm()` here / provide the context) -> stepper (tried `useForm()` here - each step is another component) and I provided the context at the right place so I don't understand why it is not storing even though I keep the reference and the data in a context. Any tips?

React Hook Form 6.0.8 and Material UI 5 alpha 4. I used the 6.0.2 and 5 alpha 2 and the same result.

Comment: Your link for the "default example from Material UI Steppers" just links to [stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `react hook form v6` then use `FormProvider`. Just make sure to define the forms for each step properly and set the state correctly for each form correctly upon clicking on next/back/finish.

Since you have not shared the code, it is not possible to say what is causing your issue. But the code in the below mention demos should surely help you.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-stepper-and-react-hook-form-v6-20c8s?file=/src/App.js) - **react-hook-form 6.0.8** and **material-ui 5.0 alpha-2**

**If you are using react-hook-form [version 5](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v6.0.0-rc.1)**, then you can use `FormContext`. [See working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-stepper-and-react-hook-form-v5-s30kc)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above worked for me, but I have to show how I made to solve my problem:

1. Create a controller on your parent component, like this:

   `const [compiledForm, setCompiledForm] = useState({});`
2. Create a watch on your form component:

   `const watchForm = watch();`
3. Add the function reset (from useForm) on useEffect:

   `useEffect(() => { reset({ ...compiledForm }); }, [compiledForm, reset]);`
4. And then you can set the watch on your form submit:
   `setCompiledForm(watchForm);`